# Delphi XE - getting around a stalled sql query due to a locked table exception

Tags: sql, delphi

Normally, I encapsulate the `query.active` in a `try/except/end` with a `messagedlg` appearing to prompt the user to retry after a few moments ...

```
try
query.active:=true;
except
if messagedlg('someone is locking the table. wait about 10 seconds before clicking retry',mtinformation,[mbretry],0) = mrretry then begin
query.active:=true;
end;
```

but this isn't ideal, since the user can just immediately click the retry,
and the query will fail if the table is still locked.

Even a dirty read doesn't sidestep the table locking.

Since automation is now a factor, with no user to attend to the prompt,
has anyone discovered a way to let the query continue attempting execution
even if the table remains locked for a bit?

Comment: Put your code into the loop and try to execute it with some delay? Would that be sufficient for you?

Comment: the delay would still be a 'best guess' as to how long to wait, and our network is the dirt road off the information superhighway of networks.

Comment: How do you look your table, what database engine do you use? What operations are performed on the locking query? You need to improve your question to let us help.

Comment: the table resides in informix, the bde is used via the generic query component. the locks to tables happen within the tecsys elite 7.6.2 dms system, and not all tables employ a separate lock table to let you know the table is locked, some of the locking is hardcoded within tecsys elite.